# Filter apache files using linux

Tags: linux, apache, logging

I'm trying to filter down a heap of apache log files to EXCLUDE all requests that have:

- The pattern `/static/`  (this is my images/js folder that I want to exclude)
- `10.xxx.xxx.xxx` (where x is any number - I don't want internal requests included)
- Any response other than `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200` - only want successes

I have a folder containing multiple .gz files. Is there a way to run a linux command that will do the proper filtering and save the results in a file called apache_log.txt?

I'm really limited in my linux knowledge so will appreciate any help greatly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each file *.gz, uncompress and filter out unwanted static and local, and filter wanted "GET 200", and append this in result file.

```
for f in *.gz ; do zcat $f | grep -v '/static/' | grep -v '10\.[0-9]\+\.\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+' | grep 'GET / HTTP/1.1" 200' >> apache_log.txt ; done
```

Or on multiple lines.

```
for f in *.gz
do
    zcat $f \
        | grep -v '/static/' \
        | grep -v '10\.[0-9]\+\.\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+' \
        | grep 'GET / HTTP/1.1" 200' \
        >> apache_log.txt
done
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am getting this error for each file in the directory (it seems to have a .Z appended to the filename)      zcat: access_log.2011072803.gz.Z: No such file or directory

Comment: Forgot the `do`, sorry: Try `for f in *.gz ; do ls -l $f ; done` to list the files.

Comment: That worked gave me a list (not complete) -rwxr-xr-x  1 chrispaynter  staff  463010049 12 Jul 00:01 access_log.2011071103.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1 chrispaynter  staff  502073947 12 Aug 10:02 access_log.2011071203.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1 chrispaynter  staff  468224970 14 Jul 00:01 access_log.2011071303.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1 chrispaynter  staff  464609043 12 Aug 10:02 access_log.2011071403.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1 chrispaynter  staff  483168852 16 Jul 00:00 access_log.2011071503.gz

Comment: So there's no reason the `for` command should not work with the `zcat` command, and magically append a `.Z` to the filenames.

Comment: I just tried the same command with zmore instead and it worked. I should have mentioned I am using a mac not sure if that makes the difference or not. Could I ask one more favor? Could you please show me what to add if I only want to output the IP address of the request?

Comment: Your friend will be `awk` for this task. `awk '{print $1;}'` will print the first field of every line (delimited by spaces).